# How to close database in Cursorloader

Tags: android-cursorloader

I'm currently working on ListViews in Fragments. The Listviews are loaded by Cursorloader, but without ContentManager. So the code looks like this and it works:

```
@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int arg0, Bundle arg1) {

    Log.d("SoapERP", "onCreateLoader");
    CursorLoader loader = new CursorLoader(getActivity()) {
    final DBHelper dbhelper1= new DBHelper(getActivity());       
        @Override
        public Cursor loadInBackground() {
            Cursor c = null;
            dbhelper1.open();
            c = dbhelper1.fetchAllMatnameswithID();
//              dbhelper1.close();
            return c;

        }

     };
    return loader;
```

My problem is that I get an LogCat-Error-Message that the database wasn't closed. But if I use dbhelper.close(); I get the Error "Database is already closed" wich is also understandable because it is just before the return statement. After the return statement code is not reachable and if I declare DBHelper dbhelper1 final the program crashes without any information in logcat. So what is my fail???

Comment: In order to prevent the error I tried to do it with a Content Provider but the problem is still the same. But I think that now I'm a bit closer to the problem - threads. I'm closing the database while the other thread is still collecting data. Now it's totally unclear to me how to get a proper solution to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/3700d1a47517b745#) the right statement as of Dianne Hackborn from android framework development: "A content provider is created when its hosting process is created, and remains around for as long as the process does, so there is no need to close the database -- it will get closed as part of the kernel cleaning up the process's resources when the process is killed. Dianne Hackborn Android framework engineer hack...@android.com " - so let's use Content Provider.